# Find Boot ROM Version in Big Sur

Tags: ssd, big-sur

I swapped a failing SSD in my MacBook Pro 15" retina Late 2013 model, which had High Sierra `v10.13.6` installed, with a NVMe ssd and directly installed Big Sur `v11.5.1` from a bootable usb. It works fine.

I am aware of sleep/hibernate issues with NVMe drives, but as per [this Macrumors thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/upgrading-2013-2014-macbook-pro-ssd-to-m-2-nvme.2034976/) (search for `6 - Hibernation issues on 2013-2014 laptops​` to arrive at the relevant section), Big Sur with Boot ROM 427.0.0.0 and higher prevent deep sleep issues without further system modifications.

But when I go to `About This Mac` > `System Report` > `Hardware`, the line for Boot ROM Version is missing there. It definitely was listed under High Sierra (I have a screenshot of it before the swap).

Currently, it shows me the following (relevant lines shown):

```
Model Identifier: Macbook Pro11,2
System Firmware Version: MBP112.0146.B00
SMC Version: 2.18f15
```

I even tried running `/usr/libexec/firmwarecheckers/eficheck/eficheck --integrity-check` and the output was:

```
EFI Version: MBP112.88Z.0146.B00.1804111138
Primary allowlist version match not found for version MBP112.88Z.0146.B00.1804111138
```

How can I figure out what is my current Boot ROM version. Any pointers?

P.S - I am aware of the workaround to completely disable deep sleep and hibernate, but I think with the right Boot ROM version i.e. 427.0.0.0 or higher, I wouldn't need to do anything at all.

Comment: What was the version before the swap and why do you think it changed in the meantime?

Comment: @nohillside It was MBP112.0146.B00, which is what I see in System Firmware Version, so they just renamed it, lol. So what's this Boot ROM v427 that's mentioned over there? During the installation, my system did kind of shutdown in the middle and I had to use the power button to bring it back up, from which it seem to just resume the installation. Not sure if that was a bios update or something?

Comment: And somewhere in that huge thread, there are people claiming they got the 427 Boot ROM with Big Sur, so what are my next steps here? Figure out whether I have an unapplied BIOS update?

Comment: I checked my mid-2015 MBP and its BIOS version was v427. And it got updated further with Big Sur v11.5.1 Also haven't seen my late-2013 model act up with sleep or hibernate at all, so it should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, `Boot ROM Version` has been renamed to `System Firmware Version`.

My mid-2015 MBP's BIOS version is indeed higher than v427, but late-2013 model uses another versioning convention. `MBP112.0146.B00` doesn't seem to be causing any sleep or hibernate issues from what I have seen today itself.